# QT CMAKE based application wrong dependency

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, mingw, qt-creator

I am currently getting a task to make this [project](https://github.com/labstreaminglayer/App-EGIAmpServer) working on Windows 10. I managed to get it compiled and build pass, I start to run it but it did not start and the output is quite simple, like below.

```
15:49:31: Starting J:\Projects\huang\build-App-EGIAmpServer-master-new_kit-Debug\EGIAmpServer.exe ...
15:49:32: The program has unexpectedly finished.
15:49:32: The process was ended forcefully.
15:49:32: J:\Projects\huang\build-App-EGIAmpServer-master-new_kit-Debug\EGIAmpServer.exe crashed.
```

Debugger log does not help much to me as below

```
>21^done
dNOTE: ENGINE SETUP OK
dState changed from EngineSetupRequested(1) to EngineSetupOk(3)
dState changed from EngineSetupOk(3) to EngineRunRequested(4)
dCALL: RUN ENGINE
<22-exec-run


>=thread-group-started,id="i1",pid="10748"
 Thread group i1 created.
dTaking notice of pid 10748
>=thread-created,id="1",group-id="i1"
 Thread 1 created.
>~"[New Thread 10748.0x2534]\n"
 [New Thread 10748.0x2534]

>=thread-exited,id="1",group-id="i1"
 Thread 1 in group i1 exited.
>=thread-group-exited,id="i1"
 Thread group i1 exited.
dNOTE: INFERIOR EXITED
dState changed from EngineRunRequested(4) to InferiorShutdownFinished(14)
dState changed from InferiorShutdownFinished(14) to EngineShutdownRequested(15)
dCALL: SHUTDOWN ENGINE
dPLAIN ADAPTER SHUTDOWN 15
dINITIATE GDBENGINE SHUTDOWN, PROC STATE: 2
<23python theDumper.exitGdb({"token":23})
>22^error,msg="During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135."
eERROR: UNEXPECTED STATE: EngineShutdownRequested  WANTED: EngineRunRequested IN C:\Users\qt\work\build\qt-creator\src\plugins\debugger\gdb\gdbengine.cpp:4480
dDuring startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.
dNOTE: ENGINE RUN FAILED
 Run failed.
dState changed from EngineShutdownRequested(15) to EngineRunFailed(5)
dState changed from EngineRunFailed(5) to EngineShutdownRequested(15)
dCALL: SHUTDOWN ENGINE
dPLAIN ADAPTER SHUTDOWN 15
dINITIATE GDBENGINE SHUTDOWN, PROC STATE: 2
<24python theDumper.exitGdb({"token":24})

dQUIT DEBUGGER REQUESTED IN STATE 15
>&"python theDumper.exitGdb({\"token\":23})\n"
dGDB PROCESS FINISHED, status 0, exit code 0
dNOTE: ENGINE SHUTDOWN FINISHED
dState changed from EngineShutdownRequested(15) to EngineShutdownFinished(16)
 Debugger finished.
dState changed from EngineShutdownFinished(16) to DebuggerFinished(17)
```

So I use `dependency walker` to see if any dll missing. Now things are getting clear it looks like QT5CORE.DLL, QT5GUI.DLL and QY5WIDGETS.DLL are wrong.

[image]

Now the question is why and what's wrong with my environment? I am using QT Creator 4.11.1, MinGW 7.3.0 64 bit(coming with QT), CMake 3.17 Win10 64 OS. My QT Creator kits is like below.

[image]

Comment: On Stack Overflow we prefer **pasting** the **text** of code/errors/logs into the question post to providing an *image* of this text. Please, replace the first two screenshots with the text. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

When running your program, you need to have the correct 64-bit Qt DLLs in the program's directory or in `PATH`.  From your screenshots, I assume you have 32-bit QtCreator's directory in `PATH` instead.